# Query if customer is new vs repeat on success page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

**What is the best way to determine if customer who just placed an order is new or repeat?**

On success page, I can get an order object via:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')-> 
loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->
getLastRealOrderId());
```

Without knowing much about magento's utility methods, next step could be to get Customer object and to check if total number or orders > 1?

If possible, include actual code in your solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to organize the all conditions.Try below code on success page.

```
<?php 
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->
getLastRealOrderId());
$customer_email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
$customer_id = $order->getCustomerId();

if ($order->getCustomerIsGuest()) { 
    //echo 'customer is guest';
    $extorders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', array('eq' => $customer_email));
} else {
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order->getQuoteId());
    if ($quote->getId()) {
        $method = $quote->getCheckoutMethod();
        if ($method == 'register'){
            //echo 'customer registered when placing the order';
            $extorders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', array('eq' => $customer_email));
        } else {
            //echo 'customer was already logged in when placing the order';
            $extorders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id);
        }
    } else {
        //echo 'there is no way of knowing if the customer registered or was already logged in but for sure an account exists.';
        $extorders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', array('eq' => $customer_email));
    }
}
//var_dump($extorders->getSize());
if ($extorders->getSize() == 1) {
    echo 'New customer come and placed first order';
} else {
    echo 'order repeat by customer';
}
?>
```

Comment: Great! I am going to test in on dev server right now. Thanks

Comment: Do we have to branch out for guests/registered/reg and logged in? Wouldn't this return all orders by email regardless of customer status: $orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection(); $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_email','email@domain.com');

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting your point.
If this answer help you please upvote me.

Comment: My questions was, if we can get $customer_email for any order, why do this: $extorders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id);

Answer (score 0):

```
$LastOrder= Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->
getLastRealOrderId());

$LastOrdertime= $LastOrder->getCreatedAt();

$OrderCollection=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$LastOrder->getData('customer_email'))
        ->setOrder('created_at','asc');
$fstoredetime= $OrderCollection->getFirstItem()->getCreatedAt();    

if($fstoredetime==$LastOrdertime):
// new customer
else:
//old customer
endif;
```

The relevant tables and fields are

- sales_flat_order - customer_id, updated_at
- customer_entity - created_at